# Fantasy book series about werewolves finding a chosen one and looking for four magic swords

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

I'm looking for a fantasy book series about werewolves finding a chosen one and looking for four magic swords. It has 3 or 4 books in it and was set in modern day 2000's or 2010's.

There were werewolves who were working for witches, and later on we find out there were four different groups of them each able to turn into different animals guarding special swords or sword pieces. They turned into the actual animals and the only other animals I can remember is a big cat like a jaguar or leopard and a bear group.

The main character is a late teens girl who was one of the werewolves and she ends up finding a chosen one guy that has a tattoo of a cross on his back that either turned out to be the 4 swords mixed together or 4 pieces of a sword that combined together. Eventually he is able to turn into a wolf too.

The werewolves were fighting against a group they thought was evil, but it turned out the witches were the evil ones all along and at the end of the series they beat them and the main girl and guy stay in wolf form.

This was a young adult or adult series I read about 8-10 years ago. Any help would be appreciated.